# Rendering JSF page in JSP using iframe

Tags: java, jsf, iframe, struts, jboss7.x

I have an old web-application running on `JBoss4 using JSP and Struts`. And another web-application running in `JBoss7 using JSF`. I want to render the JSF page in an existing JSP template page so that the user cannot see the difference.

Both JBoss4 and JBoss7 runs on different JVM and have different domains like
`example.company.com` and `example1.company.com`

Due to `Same Origin Policy` i'm not able to use iframe and render the JSF page in a JSP template as shown below

```
In Welcome.jsp (http://example.company.com/sales/welcome.jsp)

...
<iframe src="http://example1.company.com/web/home.xhtml"></iframe>
....
```

So can I implementing a proxy servlet action `redirect.do` in JBoss4 which will make a http get request to `http://example1.company.com/web/home.xhtml` and redirect that stream to the iframe like below

```
In Welcome.jsp (http://example.company.com/sales/welcome.jsp)

...
<iframe src="http://example.company.com/sales/redirect.do"></iframe>
....
```

Kindly give your suggestions on this. Thanks in advance